# Why is DeepSkyStacker output resolution off?

Tags: astrophotography, image-stacking, stars

I am using DeepSkyStacker version 3.3.2 to stack 20 light frames of some stars.

The registration and stacking goes off without a hitch, but the resulting image resolution has drastically changed. The original resolution of the light frames is 4282x2848. The resolution of the output image is only 1088x2874 , which obviously has a drastically altered aspect ratio.

The resulting output image looks like it is the far left slice of the original images. What is left, does not look like it has been scaled disproportionately in either direction, but rather just looks like an unaltered subsection of the originals.

For the registering and stacking I use recommended settings.

Has anyone run into this problem before?

Comment: Did the field of stars slew across the field of view over the course of your session? Or did your imaging instrument move with the apparent motion of the sky?

Comment: The stars moved across the field of view. This seems like a bug in 3.3.2 with canon raw files, using 3.3.4 solved the issue. I will wait to see if anyone has a more concrete answer for solving in version 3.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bug in 3.3.2 with canon raw files, using 3.3.4 solved the issue.